# Не работает required в форме

Tags: html, required

Все поля имеют атрибут `required`, обязательное поле, но даже если вообще ничего не заполнять, все равно идет отправка....

```html
<div class="content">
  <form class="form ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-last-name ng-valid-maxlength ng-valid-first-name ng-valid-patronymic ng-valid-email ng-valid-mobile-phone ng-valid-mask" name="formSignup" novalidate="" action="step2-1.html" method="POST">
    <div class="form__wrapper form1">
      <h3 class="form__title">
        <span>Контактная информация</span>
      </h3>
      <div id="fields-container">
        <div class="row form__row">
          <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
            <label class="form__label" for="signupForm.model.lastName">Фамилия</label>
            <input type="text" class="form__input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-last-name ng-valid-maxlength" name="lastName" required><span></span><span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row form__row">
          <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
            <label class="form__label" for="signupForm.model.firstName">Имя</label>
            <input type="text" class="form__input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-first-name ng-valid-maxlength" name="firstName" required><span></span><span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row form__row">
          <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
            <label class="form__label" for="signupForm.model.patronymic">Отчество</label>
            <input type="text" class="form__input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-patronymic ng-valid-maxlength" name="patronymic" required><span></span><span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row form__row">
          <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
            <label class="form__label">Электронная почта</label>
            <span class="form__row-info">Для получения договора и документов об оплате</span>
            <div class="form__field"><input type="email" class="form__input js-dadata-email ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-email" name="email" required>
              <span class="form__error">Это поле должно содержать E-Mail в формате example@site.com</span>
            </div>
            <span></span><span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row form__row">
          <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
            <label class="form__label">Пароль</label>

            <input type="password" class="form__input js-dadata-password ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-password" id="password" name="password" required><span class="form__row-info"></span>
            <span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="signupFormApiError" class="ng-hide">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form__row form_submit">
      <div class="form__submit-wrapper">
        <input type="submit" class="form__submit form_submit-next" value="&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Продолжить&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; " style="padding:11px 48px;">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ngIf: isConfirm -->
  </form>
</div>
```

Почему так?

Как исправить?

Спасибо!

Comment: novalidate вам не мешает в форме? Может убрать и проблема решится?

Comment: ех... туплю конкретно, вот что значит свежий взгляд! Спасибо!